# Change text in HTML Select Options

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is situation like this:

```
<select id="trollSelect">
    <option value="PL">Troll</option>
    <option value="EN">Troll</option>
    <option value="JP">Troll</option>
</select>
```

I want to change `$(#trollSelect option).text("NEW_VALUE")` in `$(document).ready(function() {...}` - when page is ready.

The final effect should be like that:

```
<select id="trollSelect">
    <option value="PL">Pan Troll</option>
    <option value="EN">Mr Troll</option>
    <option value="JP">Troll Sama</option>
</select>
```

I want not to use Server Side Script, it must be done in JQuery or JavaScript. Is this possible to do something like `foreach(options)`?

UPDATE:

I would want to generate Text for options in this way:

```
function getTrollText(isoCode)  // isoCode from option.val()
{
    [...] // some magic, it does not matter
    return result;  // Here will be returned the text:
                    // "Pan Troll", "Mr Troll", or "Troll Sama"
}
```

Comment: Where will the text for the updated `option` elements be coming from?

Comment: yes possible but you have some option text differences, How is it comming to put in the options text?

Comment: Coming from function getTrollText(isoCode){var text = array(...); ... return result;}

Comment: would you mind to post that array values in your question post, that would complete your question and we can suggest you answer properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newValues = ['Pan Troll','Mr Troll','Troll Sama'];
    $('#trollSelect option').each(function(i,_){
      $(this).text(newValues[i]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

as you have not mentioned how the options are gonna appear i am storing them in array. then you can iterate over the option and set the html for each option by using options index to get new text from array :

```
$(function () {
 var chngearr=['Pan Troll','Mr Troll','Troll Sama'];
 $('#trollSelect option').each(function(){
    $(this).html(chngearr[$(this).index()]);
 });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b27hb/)**

Comment: OP already mentioned about using that part. so i did not mentioned it.

Comment: OP knows it where to put so this does not matter in the answer here @AmitJoki.

Comment: @Jai fine. I thought it was a bid to make code look smaller :)

Comment: Don't panic, I know where I should to put that :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var arr = ['Pan Troll','Mr Troll','Troll Sama'];
    $('#trollSelect option').text(function (index, value) {
        return arr[index];
    });
});
```

This uses the function callback overload of `.text()`, which passes two parameters index, the actual index, which starts from 0 so it can be used to access the `arr` values

Comment: The text inside the last option would be `Troll Troll`, but `Troll Troll !== Troll Sama`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, yes I know. Updated

Answer (score 2):

Check this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/yebk4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = ['Pan Troll','Mr Troll','Troll Sama'];
        $('#trollSelect option').each(function(i){
        console.log($(this).html(arr[i]));
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = ['Pan Troll','Mr Troll','Troll Sama'];
        $.each($('#trollSelect option'),function(i){
        console.log($(this).html(arr[i]));
    });
});
```

Use **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** to iterate over the `<option>`

Comment: @AmitJoki Yes, just an alternative syntax for Op's knowledge. My fiddle does not have that method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#trollSelect option').each(function(i,_){
      $(this).text(getTrollText($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

Maybe this way will be good.